# -n redundant in command -v tests?

Tags: bash, shell

When testing for the existence of a command,

```
[ -n "$(command -v foo)" ]
```

and

```
[ "$(command -v foo)" ]
```

seem functionally equivalent, yet most examples I've seen include the `-n` test explicitly. I assume that if a command does not exist, that's equivalent to:

```
[ "" ]
```

Is it bad practice to omit `-n`?

Comment: Yes (I would regard it as bad practice), but you're probably safe unless you make a habit of looking for odd-ball command names that could be confused with options to `test` (aka `[`).  And it would have to be pretty odd-ball for it to cause problems; I can't think how you'd get, for example, a `-z` from `command -v …`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of using `-n` or not, you are testing the output of the `command` builtin. I would test it's return value:

```
if command -v "$cmd" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "command $cmd exists"
fi
```

Comment: Sometimes when asked to choose between A or B, the answer is C! :). However to generalize your question about `-n` and testing for an empty string; In most (or even all) cases it should be fine to omit the `-n`. However, being as explicit as possible is guaranteed to be safe in all cases and improves readability.